# Android Studio: How to exclude Icon\r file?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Google Drive automatically generates `Icon$'\r'` in each synced folder in OSX. I'd like to exclude this file `Icon$'r'` recursively from compilation in Android Studio.

### I tried #1 (din't work):

Adding `!/**/Icon$'\r'` and `!/**/Icon'` in the following field:

> File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings
>   Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler
>   Resource patterns:

[image]

### I tried #2 (didn't work):

Adding the following in `build.gradle` under module:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
            exclude '**/Icon$"\r"'
            // exclude '**/Icon'
        }
    }
}
```

### Note:

1. I already excluded `Icon$'\r'` in .gitignore
2. If `Icon$'\r'` is both **excluded at compilation** AND **hidden**, that'd be the best solution.